# How to change font size of all text?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to change the font size of the text inside an MS Word doc opened using Excel VBA.

```
Sub Validator()
    Dim doc As Word.document
    lngAccountCounter = 3
    Dim wordapp As Word.Application

    Set wordapp = New Word.Application
    wordapp.documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Account.doc"
    wordapp.Visible = True
    wordapp.Activate

    With wordapp.Selection
        .Font.Size = 7
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53229662/edit) so we know what the question is? At the moment, we don't know). While you're at it, you can also either remove the `Excel` tags or explain how this has to do with Excel

Comment: Hi sorry for the ambiguity. I changed it, I hope you understood it. I'm trying to change the font size of the text in the word doc to size 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this

```
With wordapp.Selection
    .Font.Size = 7
End With
```

To

```
ActiveDocument.Select
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Font.Size = 7
```